# Models of ZF with $\mathbb{R}$ "bigger than the continuum"?

Tags: set-theory

The discussion on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4573147) seems to raise the possibility of a model of ZF having a "non-standard" set of reals, namely by an ultrapower construction making

> the (external size) of the reals of the model to be much larger than the continuum is supposed to be...but each model thinks that its real numbers are the unique Dedekind complete field

I'm wondering how exactly this can happen. I was under the impression that "the reals" of a model is the power set of $\omega$ in that model (or a set of equal cardinality). In which case: how can the model's $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ be "much larger than the continuum is supposed to be"? That would seem to imply that there could exist a set $X$ whose members are exclusively subsets of $\omega$, yet $X$ is nonetheless "larger than the continuum is supposed to be", which sounds like a contradiction. Maybe the aforementioned ultrapower construction produces a model with a non-standard notion of natural numbers (non-standard $\omega$)? Or produces a model that somehow "thinks" that $\mathbb{R}$ is a set of cardinality larger than $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$?

Comment: Your second-to-last sentence is exactly the answer.

Comment: OK, makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: If you can deal with "the set that the model thinks is the real numbers is actually countable", then there shouldn't be a problem with the converse.

Comment: @NoahSchweber , one thought: If a model $\mathcal{M}$ contains a set of non-standard natural numbers, surely(?) it nonetheless *also* contains the ***standard*** $\mathbb{N}$ (i.e. the set of all finite von Neumann ordinals), and thus also contains the standard reals (powerset of standard $\mathbb{N}$)...(cont'd)

Comment: ...So as to whether "the reals" of $\mathcal{M}$ are "larger than the continuum is supposed to be", it seems like the answer depends on which sets you *choose* as "naturals" and "reals" in $\mathcal{M}$ (e.g. choose the standard or non-standard $\mathbb{N}$ as the domain of Peano arithmetic in $\mathcal{M}$). Correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: @NikS, there is a predicate in the language of ZF saying "this set is the smallest nonzero limit ordinal", and it's a theorem of ZF that there is a unique set satisfying this predicate. So when we talk about "the naturals of a model $\mathcal M$", we mean "the unique element of $\mathcal M$ satisfying that predicate". This object may be nonstandard - and if it is, then it contains a copy of the standard naturals, but $\mathcal M$ itself doesn't "know" this copy exists. So you can't apply the powerset axiom to this copy! (What we mean by "the reals of $\mathcal M$" is a similar idea to this.)